# Why is a CSRF POST request to 'localhost:8000' successful, but '127.0.0.1:8000' is not?

Tags: python, django, cors, csrf

My frontend (React) and backend (Django) are decoupled, runnning on `localhost:3000` and `127.0.0.1:8000` respectively.

Consider the following frontend request:

```
async function test() {
    let token = await getCsrfToken() // fetched from other endpoint
    let url = 'http://localhost:8000/test'
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': token,
        },
        credentials: 'include',
    })
    let response_text = await response.text()
    return response_text
}
test()
```

to the following endpoint:

```
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

It works fine. But if I change:

```
let url = 'http://localhost:8000/test'
```

to:

```
let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test'
```

it will fail with:

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /test

Per my understanding, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are supposed to be synonymous. Why isn't it so in this context?

What confuses me even more is that the Django's development server explicitly runs on `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Note: I am using `django-cors-headers` middleware and the following CORS/CSRF settings:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:3000']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['localhost:3000']
```

Comment: Try changing to `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000']
`

Comment: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are not considered same-domain as far as browsers are concerned. Browsers handle domains and origins based on exact matches against hostnames.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: Thanks. But since Django server is running on 127.0.0.1, why is the request to localhost successful, and 127.0.0.1 is not? Should it not be the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 127.0.0.1 and localhost are considered different domains, at least in my case. Therefore, when the CSRF token is sent from the backend to the frontend, an additional configuration is needed.
In my

```
@GetMapping("/csrf")
public CsrfToken csrfToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, "XSRF-TOKEN=" + (token == null ? "" : token.getToken()) + "; Path=/; SameSite=Lax; Secure");
    return token;
}
```

the important part to add its the
`SameSite=Lax; Secure`
this will work but if not then look at samesite none,lax,strict documentation to see what you really need

- SameSite=None: Cookies are sent in all requests, both same-site and cross-site. However, they require the cookie to be secure, meaning it is accessed over HTTPS.
- SameSite=Lax: Cookies are sent in some cross-site requests, but only when two conditions are met: the request must be a top-level navigation (like when the URL in the address bar changes for example, a user clicking a link to go to another site) and the method of the request must be safe (for example, GET or HEAD, but not POST).
- SameSite=Strict: Cookies are never sent in cross-site requests, not even in top-level navigations. This means that if a user is on site-a.com and clicks a link to site-b.com, the SameSite=Strict cookies from site-a.com will not be sent with the request.

im using samesite=lax for now just because 127.0.0.1 and localhost are http and not https, so i cant use samesite=none

Comment: did you write all of this yourself?